# Rarefaction, community matrix and for loops

Tags: r, loops, vegan

I am a new R user so I apologize ahead of time for my ignorance.  I have a community matrix of stream macroinvertebrate data (plots as row headings and species as column headings). I would like to rarefy the data to 500 individuals per plot, do this 1000 times, and then calculate a metric of stream health (e.g., % EPT). At this point, I have not had success at building a loop to rarefy the data 1000 times (or even 10 times).  I am using a simplified data set (6 species, 12 plots) to figure out the proper code since my community matrix has > 100 species.  I am using this website (http://ichthyology.usm.edu/courses/multivariate/diversity.R) as a template for developing the proper code. Thank you in advance for any help with this code.

My matrix with 6 species, 12 plots

```
comm
    X Attenella.margarita Baetidae Baetis.sp. Baetis.tricaudatus Caenis.sp. Diphetor.hageni
1   1                   0        0          0                  0          0              36
2   2                   0        0          0               1009          0             682
3   3                  51       51          0                609          0             406
4   4                   0        0         40                  0          0               0
5   5                   0        0         68                  0         68             203
 6   6                   0        0          0               1244          0               0
 7   7                   0        0       2090                  0          0               0
 8   8                   0        0         11                  0          0               0
 9   9                   0        0          0               4621          0               0
 10 10                   0        0          0               1515          0               0
 11 11                   0        0          0                 33          0               0
 12 12                   0        0          0                116          0               0
```

> 

I can `rarefy` this data set 1x using the vegan package, but I would like to do this repeatedly

```
rrarefy(comm, sample=5)
      X Attenella.margarita Baetidae Baetis.sp. Baetis.tricaudatus Caenis.sp. Diphetor.hageni
 [1,] 0                   0        0          0                  0          0               5
 [2,] 0                   0        0          0                  4          0               1
 [3,] 0                   2        0          0                  2          0               1
 [4,] 0                   0        0          5                  0          0               0
 [5,] 0                   0        0          1                  0          1               3
 [6,] 0                   0        0          0                  5          0               0
 [7,] 0                   0        0          5                  0          0               0
 [8,] 3                   0        0          2                  0          0               0
 [9,] 0                   0        0          0                  5          0               0
 [10,] 0                   0        0          0                  5          0               0
 [11,] 0                   0        0          0                  5          0               0
 [12,] 0                   0        0          0                  5          0               0
```

but I have no luck when trying to do this as a loop 10 times

```
> ComLoop = 0
> for (i in 1:10) ComLoop[i] = rrarefy(comm, sample=5)
  Warning in ComLoop[i] = rrarefy(comm, sample = 5) :
```

Comment: if you don't get an answer here in a day or two, you might try posting (giving a link to this attempt) to the r-sig-ecology@r-project.org list, where you will find other people who understand the context of the question better ...

Answer (score 1):

Would something like that solve your problem?

```
res <- lapply(as.list(1:10), function(x) rrarefy(comm, sample=5))
```

There are certainly more elegant solutions, but I don't really understand what rarefaction is doing, and your link did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `ComLoop` is a numeric vector and `rrarefy()` returns a data frame of community data. So you are trying to shove an entire data frame into a single element of a numeric vector. That won't work.

@tophcito's Answer will work because it returns a list whose components are the result of the five separate calls to `rrarefy()`.

The loop version can be done as follows:

```
require(vegan)
data(dune)
ComLoop <- vector(mode = "list", length =  5)
for (i in seq_along(ComLoop)) {
    ComLoop[[i]] <- rrarefy(dune, sample = 5)
}
```

Which gives

```
> str(ComLoop)
List of 5
 $ : num [1:20, 1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:20] "2" "13" "4" "16" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:30] "Belper" "Empnig" "Junbuf" "Junart" ...
 $ : num [1:20, 1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:20] "2" "13" "4" "16" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:30] "Belper" "Empnig" "Junbuf" "Junart" ...
 $ : num [1:20, 1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:20] "2" "13" "4" "16" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:30] "Belper" "Empnig" "Junbuf" "Junart" ...
 $ : num [1:20, 1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:20] "2" "13" "4" "16" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:30] "Belper" "Empnig" "Junbuf" "Junart" ...
 $ : num [1:20, 1:30] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:20] "2" "13" "4" "16" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:30] "Belper" "Empnig" "Junbuf" "Junart" ...
```

In other words, a list whose components are each a data frame generated by from random community matrix of rarefied data (to the `sample` stated).

Note that in creating the `ComLoop` list to hold the results, I was being explicit about the length. You don't *need* to be explicit about the length as growing a list is one area where you don't *need* to pre-allocate storage. So you could do this:

```
ComLoop <- list()
```

But then you can't use the `seq_along()` idiom that I used above. There you'd need to state explicitly the values `i` should take as you did originally:

```
for(i in 1:5)
    ComLoop[i] <- rrarefy(dune, sample = 5)
```

I think it is better practice to set up the size of loop you need, hence my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

user1943324, I too am attempting to rarefy then calculate invertebrate metrics such as %EPT. 
However I am taking a different approach and have run into stumbling blocks with limited r-programming experience.

I assume you are trying to produce the rarefied matrix many times to then count the number of EPT taxa in each rarefaction run and calculate a mean and variability.

Instead, could we alter the existing rarfy{vegan} code to allow for user defined traits (e.g. EPT or not, functional feeding group, or tolerance value) and in addition to the existing total taxa richness count averaged over multiple runs, use an IF THAN type command to average the taxa richness of each individual trait state over those runs?

There would be no need to produce multiple output matrices.